# jquery error, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'scrollLeft' in undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

when  ABC  is loaded,
How to remove this (in fadeout effect)

I tried

view.html

```
    <%if notice %>
      <span class = "notice"><%= flash[:notice] %> </span>
    <% end %>

<script>

<script>

$( "span.notice" ).ready(function() {
  $( this ).fadeOut( 1000, function() {
    $( this ).remove();
  });
});
</script>
```

I received error message that

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
jquery-1.10.2.js:6820 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'display' in undefine
```

How to I fix it?

Comment: Have you included `jQuery` properly?

Comment: Probably, because it's a `jquery-1.10.2.js` error.

Comment: @jung_digit : if answer really help then please correct it because if someone else having same issue than it easily find correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

`$( "span.notice" ).ready(` ? I don't think so. The DOM can be ready, but you can't listen for a HTML element to be. Just remove this, and also the double `<script>` opening.

```
<script>
$( "span.notice" ).fadeOut( 1000, function() {
    $( this ).remove();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'd wrap what you wrote inside `jQuery(function($) { ... });`.

Comment: No need, because the script is placed after the element it targets.

Comment: Right. Isn't it good convention to still do so, even if no need?

Comment: It's not a convention. Indenting is a convention, properCaseVariables are a convention. But this is code. Useless code. It's added only when needed, that's it, and here, it's not needed.

Comment: Thank you. this answer is more simple.

Comment: Nice :) If it's okay to you, could you please validate it?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $( 'span.notice').fadeOut( 1000, function() {
        $('span.notice').remove();
      });
});
```

You can not use ready on "span.notice".. so you need to use dom element and on dom ready you need to fadout and then remove your span. Please make sure you have added necessary jquery files in proper manner.

Comment: Thank you!! I'm not good at jquery.. I must study more.. Thank You!!

Comment: please check fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gLahmhav/1/ hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah good, that's exactly my answer, with a useless `$( document ).ready` and a double DOM request v_v